# Syslog-ng truncates lines when writing to output log

Tags: syslog-ng

OS: SLes 11 sp4
syslog-ng: syslog-ng-2.0.9-27.34.39.2

Hi,

syslog-ng is configured to read from a application log file and then send it to another file in /var/log (tcpdump is not installed, I cant install it on a blackbox so this is how I test my config)

I have the following in my  syslog-ng configuration file:

```
source ESRS {
file("/opt/esrsve/gateway/xGate.log");
};

destination esrsfile{ file("/var/log/max.log" );};



log { source(ESRS);
destination(esrsfile);
};
```

The problem I am seeing is that when  syslog writes  to the outputfile (esrsfile) it truncatedthe lines.

ex: Source File : 
[ 0,  6,  1, 1007] 08-29-2016 13:56:28.703 IMPORTANT INFO EDDEMC: Data Item::PMStatus **Current Value::Offline**

And   the destination file looiks like this:

...
...
Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname C

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname u

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname r

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname r

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname e

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname n

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname t

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname V

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname a

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname l

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname u

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname e

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname :

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname :

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname O

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname f

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname f

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname l

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname i

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname n

Aug 29 14:00:02 hostname e

...
...

What is wrong here please?

Comment: Hi, can you post the entire syslog-ng configuration? Also, do the earlier parts of the message appear in the output? You might also want to try a newer version of syslog-ng, you can find packages for SLES here: https://syslog-ng.org/3rd-party-binaries/

Answer (score 0):

When you look closely, the lines are not truncated, but one log entry spreads over multiple lines, character by character. It happens usually, when the log writer flushes after writing every single character.

Make sure the writer buffers lines and sends them as one single message.